# Working with JList

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlist, string-concatenation

I I have JList and JList model that contains values of  database fields (`student` table).

I want to get all the data form the JList and store the data in String variable call `mySql`

I want the data to be stored like this:
-"SELECT " 
- then the data from jList separated by comma
-" FROM"

How can I do this?

This is what I did so far:

```
ListModel a = myList.getModel();
String obj = null;
String obj2 = null;
System.out.print("SELECT ");

for (int i = 0; i < a.getSize(); i++) {
  if (i == a.getSize() - 1) {
    obj = (String) a.getElementAt(i);
    System.out.print(obj);
  } else {
    obj2 = a.getElementAt(i) + ",";
    System.out.print(obj2);
  }
}
System.out.print(" FROM ");
```

I changed the code to this

```
    ListModel a = list2.getModel();
    String obj = null;
    String obj2 = null;
  //  System.out.print("SELECT ");

    for (int i = 0; i < a.getSize(); i++) {
        if (i == a.getSize() - 1) {
            obj = (String) a.getElementAt(i);
        //    System.out.print(obj);
        } else {
            obj2 = a.getElementAt(i) + ",";
         //   System.out.print(obj2);        
        }
                    System.err.println("This is obj2 "+obj2 +"This is obj "+ obj);        


    }
   // System.out.print("SELECT "+obj2+obj+" FROM ");
```

Comment: To be clear you want the output to be: "SELECT ele1, ele2, ..., elen FROM" ? where ele1 to elen are selected elements from your list?

Comment: yes that exactly what I want

Comment: And what's wrong with your code so far?

Comment: I want to print both obj and obj2 in the same print statement , but I can't if I put the system.out.print outside the if statement I get only                             System.err.println("This is obj2 "+obj2 +"This is obj "+ obj);  then I get something like this with out SELECT and FROM      
 This is obj2 STUDENT_ID,This is obj null
This is obj2 STUDENT_ID,This is obj STUDENT_NAME

Comment: Where is the "this is obj2" coming from?

Comment: it print statement System.out.print("This is obj2" + obj2 +"This is obj" + obj);

Comment: that print statement is not in your code example. Please post your current attempt at the problem

Comment: If you just write `for(int i = 0 ; i < a.getSize() ; i++){System.out.println(a.getElementAt(i));}` what's the output?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding them to a string then outputting that at the end? So some thing like
          `String text = "SELECT "`
then add the other strings on by
      `text =+ "whatever"`

Comment: Yes I tried that I got only the first and last element from the JList model

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't casting obj2 to string?

Comment: How many elements should you be getting? It doesn't look like anything is wrong. Are you sure you should be getting more than 2 elements out of the model?

Comment: yeah I should get 5 elements , but I only get the first and last elements .. I'm not sure where did I go wrong I think the code should work fine but it not

Comment: Try outputting the size of the model just to make sure.

Comment: I printed the size and got 5

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to get back. Did you sort this? If not, copy in here exactly what is printed out.

Comment: @geekStar I know it's commented out but I'm suspect of this line: `System.out.print("SELECT "+obj2+obj+" FROM ");`. This could likely give you the behaviour you're talking about. I think you're adding to the string in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

When you want to print the "SELECT ele,ele,ele,ele FROM" String out, then the following could be what you want:

```
ListModel a = myList.getModel();
System.out.print("SELECT ");
for (int i = 0; i < a.getSize(); i++) {
  System.out.print(a.getElementAt(i);
  if (i < a.getSize() - 1) {
    System.out.print(",");
  }
}
System.out.print(" FROM ");
```